# Materialize CSS Sidenav and Content

Tags: html, css, materialize

I'm using `Materialize CSS` to design my portfolio and having some issues now. The screenshot of what my website looks for now is this:

[image]

As you can see, the About part is below the nav which is my problem. I want it to be moved to the right so that it can be seen. My code for now is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!--Import Font awesome Icon Font-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!--Import materialize.css-->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.css"  media="screen,projection"/>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <ul id="staggered-list" class="side-nav fixed grey darken-4 blue-grey-text text-lighten-4 go">
        <br />
        <div style="text-align:center;" id="profilepic">
          <img src="./images/robertsoriano.jpg" alt="" class="circle responsive-img" width="200"> <br />
          Robert Soriano
        </div>
        <br /> <br />
        <li><a  class="grey-text text-lighten-2" href="#"><i class="fa fa-user fa-2x fa-fw"></i>Home</a></li>
        <li><a id="links" class="pink-text lighten-2" href="#"><i class="fa fa-terminal fa-2x fa-fw"></i>Projects</a></li>
        <li><a id="links" class="green-text text-lighten-2" href="#"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart fa-2x fa-fw"></i>Skills</a></li>
        <li><a id="links" class="yellow-text text-lighten-2" href="#"><i class="fa fa-graduation-cap fa-2x fa-fw"></i>Education</a></li>
        <li><a id="links"class="blue-text text-lighten-2" href="#"><i class="fa fa-code fa-2x fa-fw"></i>Source Codes</a></li>
      </ul>
    </header>
    <main>
      <div class="section">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col s12 m9">
              <h1 class="header center-on-small-only">About</h1>
              <h4 class ="light red-text text-lighten-4 center-on-small-only">Learn about the Material Design and our Project Team.</h4>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
    <!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
      Materialize.fadeInImage('#profilepic');
      Materialize.showStaggeredList('#staggered-list');
      });

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**style.css**

```
body {
    background-image: url("../images/small_steps.png");
    background-color: #cccccc;
}

.go a:before,
.go a:after {
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s, opacity 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.3s, opacity 0.2s;
    transition: transform 0.3s, opacity 0.2s;
}

.go a:before {
    margin-right: 10px;
    content: '[';
    -webkit-transform: translate(20px);
    -moz-transform: translate(20px);
    transform: translate(20px);
}

.go a:after {
    margin-left: 10px;
    content: ']';
    -webkit-transform: translate(-20px);
    -moz-transform: translate(-20px);
    transform: translate(-20px);
}

.go a:hover:before,
.go a:hover:after,
.go a:focus:before,
.go a:focus:after {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px);
    -moz-transform: translate(0px);
    transform: translate(0px);
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ugwwxk64/

Any help would be really much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Can you create a demo of the exact output? Use http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: This won't be possible without having a look at your css. Can you please add that to the question.

Comment: can you post your css sir?

Comment: sure guys give me a second.

Comment: I guess you get the overlapping after certain screen size.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The overlapping occurs only when the screen is above 991px. So you need to assign some padding for the `main` element for the specific screen size.

```
@media (min-width: 991px) {
  main {
    padding-left: 120px;
  }
}
```

[**Updated JSfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Manojkr/ugwwxk64/2/embedded/result/)

Comment: @TomaszMularczyk Thanks, when did they change? Can you show the source please? :)

Comment: http://materializecss.com/grid.html checkout section "creating responsive layouts" - large screen > 992px

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col s2">
        <ul id="staggered-list" class="side-nav fixed grey darken-4 blue-grey-text text-lighten-4 go">
    <br />
    <div style="text-align:center;" id="profilepic">
      <img src="./images/robertsoriano.jpg" alt="" class="circle responsive-img" width="200"> <br />
      Robert Soriano
    </div>
    <br /> <br />
    <li><a  class="grey-text text-lighten-2" href="#"><i class="fa fa-user fa-2x fa-fw"></i>Home</a></li>
    <li><a id="links" class="pink-text lighten-2" href="#"><i class="fa fa-terminal fa-2x fa-fw"></i>Projects</a></li>
    <li><a id="links" class="green-text text-lighten-2" href="#"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart fa-2x fa-fw"></i>Skills</a></li>
    <li><a id="links" class="yellow-text text-lighten-2" href="#"><i class="fa fa-graduation-cap fa-2x fa-fw"></i>Education</a></li>
    <li><a id="links"class="blue-text text-lighten-2" href="#"><i class="fa fa-code fa-2x fa-fw"></i>Source Codes</a></li>
  </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col s10">
```

Some content...

Answer (score 1):

I have updated it: https://jsfiddle.net/ugwwxk64/24/

This is the code I included in your code:

```
<style>
    body
    {
        padding-left: 240px;
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width : 992px) 
    {
     body 
     {
        padding-left: 0;
     }
    }
</style>
```

The default width of sideNav of MaterializeCSS is 240px. Therefore, I added padding-left:240px; in the body which says that move the contents 240px from the left. Then the @media only screen and (max-width : 992px) hides rewrites the padding-left into 0 if the screen size is less than 991px. :)